# what does uniform convergent and convergent means in a normed vector space with sup norm

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological space and $V$ be a normed vector space and $C(X,V)$be the space of continuous function from $X$ to $V$.
I was told that: if I want to show a sequence of functions converges to some functions in a space of continuous functions, where V is endowed with sup norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$, I need to show it is "uniform convergent". I'm a bit confused about the difference between the definition of regular convergent of a sequence of $\{f_n\}$ functions to some $f$ i.e. $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N>0$ such that $\|f_n-f\|<\epsilon$ for $n>N$. and the definition of uniform convergent, it seems that they are the same thing when I google the definition for uniform convergent. Or is the definition with the $\epsilon-\delta$?

Comment: Convergence w.r.t the sup norm is same as uniform convergence by the very definition.

Comment: @geetha290krm Hi thanks for the comment. Ok, I think I was confused with the word uniform with the uniform continuity of functions.  But by looking at the definition of uniform convergence  I don't see any difference with a regular convergent definition. Both of which states that for all epsilon>0 there exists N>0 such that $\|f_n-f\|<\epsilon$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. It took centuries to be answered correctly.

The pointwise convergence means that for each $\epsilon$ and $x_0$ there is a $\delta$. But this $\delta$ may become bigger and bigger depending on $x_0$.

The uniform convergence means that for each $\epsilon$ there is a $\delta$ that does the work for every $x_0$.

If you need more details or rigour, just say.

Comment: Hi, thanks, that helped me understand them a bit better. But why doesn't pointwise convergence work with when showing a sequence converge under the norm?